# SSIS variable expression from SQL Execution task incorrectly set

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis, expression, etl

I have a SSIS package where I am running a SQL execution task to get some records, Then I am running a foreach loop iterating over ADO object returned and setting few variables values.

These variables are used for data flow task queries. I need to set expression for the variable.

In rows I have value something similar to `"foo" + @[User::Bar] + "baz"` (I set it using this expression directly, it works. I want to set it from sql output)

But when I get this value from SQL task to Variable expression, SSIS is escaping the quotes, I do not want to escape these for my task to work.

> Saved Value : "foo" + @[User::Bar] + "baz"
>
> Variable set : \"foo\" + @[User::Bar] + \"baz\"

Can anyone help me with this. I want expression as I have saved, due to this forceful escaping, my query is not getting set properly.

Comment: Does the provided answer solve the problem?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, will update tomorrow

Comment: Nope... It didn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Removing escape character using SSIS expression

If the following value is stored within a variable (example `@[User::Var1]`:

> \"foo\" + @[User::Bar] + \"baz\"

Add an Expression task with the following expression:

```
@[User::Var1] = REPLACE(@[User::Var1],"\\","")
```

Or create an new variable with the following expression:

```
REPLACE(@[User::Var1],"\\","")
```

#### Experiments

I created a variable `@[User::Variable]` of type string with the following **value**:

```
\"foo\" + @[User::Bar] + \"baz\"
```

Then i created another variable  `@[User::Variable1]` of type string with the following **expression**:

```
REPLACE( @[User::Variable],"\\","")
```

The value escape characters are gone:

[image]

### Update 1 - Convert Value to expression

Since you are looking to treat the following value `\"foo\" + @[User::Bar] + \"baz\"` as an expression and not a fixed value. You cannot achieve that using SSIS expression. You have to assign this value as expression to another variable as mentioned below:

I added 3 variable into my package: `Bar`, `Var1`, and `VarResult`

[image]

I added a Script task and selected `Var1` as Readonly variable and `VarResult` as ReadWriteVariable:

[image]

Inside the script i used the following code to assign the value of `Var1` as expression into `VarResult` after removing escape character:

```cs
public void Main()
{
    string Var1 = Dts.Variables["Var1"].Value.ToString();

    Dts.Variables["VarResult"].Expression = Var1.Replace("\\", "");
    Dts.Variables["VarResult"].EvaluateAsExpression = true;

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

*Result*

[image]

Comment: It didn't solve my problem.... It did remove slashes from value for initially set values but it did not at run time... Also to note, I want to set expression using that, not value.... I mean if @[User:Bar] is coming in value it's of no use to me... I want Bar variables value to be used in expression to get the value

Comment: @ChaitanyaGadkari If the string `@[User::Bar]` is stored into a variable value then it cannot be converted to this variable value since it is not used in expression. You need to achieve that using a Script Task. I will provide an answer in a while and let you know

Comment: @ChaitanyaGadkari I updated my answer, check it out